# How to print out stored HTML from Database?

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am using a [HTML rich text editor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) in a HTML form, the data from the rich text editor gets inserted into a MySQL database table into a column called `first_page` who's type is set to 'TEXT'.

So if in my rich text editor I have the following text:

`<h4 style="text-align: center;">Write your first page!</h4>`

Before I insert the data I do the following to keep the data safe from any HTML injection:

`trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($variable)));`

Then when I submit the form the data looks like this in the database:

`&lt;h4 style=&quot;text-align: center;&quot;&gt;Write your first page!&lt;/h4&gt;`

Then when I write a query and print out the value of my column on a separate page, it doesn't interpret the HTML instead it outputs the data like a normal string as shown below:

[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong here, what I would like is to have the HTML actually print out as HTML rather than a string.

**RESOLVED**

As @quentin has suggested, I have now used a [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to prevent against stuff like XSS. The actual answer to my question was to decode my HTML back to their applicable characters using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You need to convert the `HTML entities` back to their markup, using `html_entity_decode` for instance. http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @MarioWerner Fantastic, that worked. If you can write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Uhm... *don't* `htmlspecialchars` your HTML...!? Of course, then you're open for HTML injection. Can't have it both ways. You'll need a good selective sanitisation library if you want to accept HTML without accepting *arbitrary* HTML.

Comment: What's with the down votes? If I've done it wrong then correcting me is enough right? some people just can't keep their fingers away from the down vote button.

Comment: @user3574492 Don't take downvotes personal. In this case you got downvotes because it is a "quick & dirty" solution. It works, but you will run into other problems eventually.

Comment: There is no point in encoding the text with `htmlspecialchars` and then converting it back with `html_entity_decode`. You should remove `htmlspecialchars.` not add `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert the HTML entities back to their markup, using html_entity_decode for instance. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

But keep in mind that this is a "quick & dirty" solution, like using RegEx to parse HTML. I would recommend to listen to what Quentin wrote in the answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are taking to make your site safe from XSS is to ban users from inputting raw HTML into the database.

You can't simultaneously ban raw HTML and allow raw HTML to be submitted.

You need to replace the call to `htmlspecialchars` with a different mechanism to protect against XSS (such as running the input through a DOM parser and [filtering](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php%20html%20filter%20library%20XSS) the tags and attributes with a whitelist).

(You should also replace `stripslashes` (which is ineffective against SQL injection) with [prepared statements and placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).)